# Is there a possible way to do DOM selection like this? editing a string to match the id of an html element

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a small RGB color guessing game and I was thinking of finding an efficient way to do DOM selection of my html td elements. I initially thought that this should work but I recognized that the errors are due to the fact that I have to select the "object" by using quotes inside
`document.getElementById("....");`
I was wondering if there is any other way to select this element in this for loop.

This is the error message on Chrome:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at gameRefresh

HTML:

```
<table id="displayed_colors">
    <tr >
        <td id="display_color1">C1</td>
        <td id="display_color2">C2</td>
        <td id="display_color3">C3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td id="display_color4">C4</td>
        <td id="display_color5">C5</td>
        <td id="display_color6">C6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var r;
var g;
var b;
var rgb_str;

function gameRefresh(){

    for (var i = 1; i < num_of_colors + 1; i++) {
        randomRGB();
        var color_to_disp = "display_color" + i;

        console.log(r, g, b);
        color_to_disp = "\"" + color_to_disp + "\"";
        console.log(color_to_disp);

        document.getElementById(color_to_disp).style.backgroundColor = rgb_str;
    }
}
function randomRGB(){
    r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 0);
    g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 0);
    b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 0);
    rgb_str = "rgb (" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not caused by `getElementById`, but because of this line:

```
color_to_disp = "\"" + color_to_disp + "\"";
```

Removing it makes the error disappear, but the table cells are still not being colored and that's because there's a redundant empty space between `rgb` and `(` in your `rgb_str`, so change:

```
rgb_str = "rgb (" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
```

to:

```
rgb_str = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
```

However, you should consider using [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/template_strings) to improve readability of the code:

```
rgb_str = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
```

Also, instead of `getElementById` it might be better to use [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) as it's more versatile.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nve4kjf8/19/ based on the code you provided.

And here's an example with my "improvements": http://jsfiddle.net/nve4kjf8/20/